# How to write and run apache Giraph Custom code?

Tags: java, giraph

I have been  working on giraph from last 10 days.I got the ideas how to install and execute the given examples in Giraph. But I want to design my own custom code,so i need some help of you.If anyone is done with this please let me know and give some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to create a new project, a package foo and a class foo1 in that package. this project must reference to giraph-core jar files. class foo1 must extends class AbstractComputation. You should override compute function of AbstractComputation. In the compute function you will develop your own graph algorithm based on vertex-oriented paradigm.

For more information about how to implement your own algorithm, you can examples provided in giraph-examples package of giraph like SimpleConnectedComponents.java and SingleSourceShortestPaths.java.

After you implement foo1, you should create a jar file from your project and pass this jar file into your command using -libjars parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for tour quick response.How to use -libjars  in my command i am using      hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /shortestpaths -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false  For running it.can you provide me some sample code for it.

Comment: hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hado‌​op-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner -libjars [path-to-your-jar-file]/foo.jar foo.foo1 -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /shortestpaths -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false

Comment: Hi thanks...but when i try to do that its showing an error as Not a valid JAR: /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hado‌​‌​op-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hado‌​‌​op-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner -libjars /home/GiraphCustom010615/example.jar giraphsample.MaxVal -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /shortestpaths -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false  here example.jar is my jar file and giraphsample is the package and class is MaxVal

Comment: try this: hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hado‌​‌​‌​op-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner -libjars /home/GiraphCustom010615/example.jar,/usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hado‌​‌​‌​op-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar giraphsample.MaxVal -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /shortestpaths -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false here example.jar

Comment: also append these two jar files into your HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop-env.sh

Comment: Thanx Masoud for your help...I did all configuration according to your input but still facing same issue.can you explain me if i want to run it in eclipse how to do it.how to write my configuration class i.e giraphRunner calss for a giraph code.

Comment: Hi Guys Thanks a lot for cooperation .i solved the issue and i am also able to run it from eclipse.